# access UNC share in windows azure

Tags: unc

i would like to know if its possible to share a folder from the windows azure vm and then access that folder from my home pc by typing

```
\\server-address\shard folder
```

. i understand that shared folders may not be the best idea for over the internet file sharing but this what fits my needs best . im not worried about security or anything other than being able to get to the shared by typing

```
\\server-address\shard folder
```

is this possible ? if so how ?

Thank you .